# Hotkey in Eclipse to switch member of method

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I would like to know if a hot key exists which switch members of method:

```
property.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)
```

Use hot key:

```
BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(property)
```

It would be great to quickly revolve sonar alerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in Eclipse there is no refactoring therefore. And hence no Hotkey either.

The only thing that comes close to this is the 'invert equals' quick fix. If you have a line of code like this

```java
foo.equals( bar );
```

You can position the cursor on the `equals` method and use <kbd>Ctrl + 1</kbd> > *Invert equals* to swap foo and bar to

```java
bar.equals( foo );
```

But again, this refactoring is restricted to `equals`. If you think this is a generally useful feature, I recommend to open an enhancement request.

Comment: It doesn't work on compareTo but it's good to know for equals thanks a lot.